# ppa error add-apt-repository ppa:guacamole/stable

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, apt, guacamole

i'm getting this error while trying to add the ppa for apache guacamole to my ubuntu server.  i was following the guide [here](https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/0.9.0/gug/installing-guacamole.html).  it looks like the InRelease archive is found, but I get an error on the Release archive.  Is there a way to work around this?  Can I use the InRelease archive and not the Release one?  It's obviously easier to install via apt-install, but if I have to do it another way I'm not opposed.
thanks.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:guacamole/stable
 The most recent stable release of Guacamole and its components. The packages here use the same packaging as the downstream Debian and Ubuntu packages, but are updated more frequently, usually while the corresponding downstream packages are under official review.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~guacamole/+archive/ubuntu/stable
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease      
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease    
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/guacamole/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease     
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/guacamole/stable/ubuntu bionic Release         
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done                      
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/guacamole/stable/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Answer (score 0):

The ppa is not maintained anymore. The latest package there is from 2013 :/
So, you need to use a tutorial to install it from source.